# Save mp4 file to local storage iOS

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I'm developing a mobile app in both android and iOS, I didn't had issue on android while using **$cordovaFileTransfer**.  When I transfer to iOS I encountered a problem where accessing a persistent storage (by using **cordova.file.***) sometimes makes the location available and sometimes null.  Before I asked a question why does the location becomes null sometime.  And now I saw that it shows the error "**You don't have permission to access the filesystem**".  Is there a way for me to give permission to app while it's running?  I tried  **cordova-diagnostic-plugin** but it will only check if the app is permitted but no control on the permission.

Comment: Suggest you to have a look at this link - https://github.com/gandhirajan/Cordova_File_Operations which has the working sample for storing file in both Android and iOS devices Let me know if it helps

Comment: i'll check it out thanks for the link

Comment: Please keep me posted

Comment: well the functionality from the example of the url you gave me, worked.  and I know it's asking of what app should i open for the mp4 to play, but my problem is that, applying the code to my app, I'm getting nativeURL undefined, searching on this now

Comment: In that case you gotta post your code and point out where exactly your code is failing

Comment: i just copied and pasted the code in a controller, nothing different. i even copied and pasted the jquery.js

Comment: Ensure that you got the directory properly before invoking nativeURL on it

Comment: I understand the logic now, cordova.file.* will be null if it is accessed when device is ready.  I have different problem now.. why does document.addEventListener('deviceready' only hits after I exit the app? how can I make the device ready from every time it's being opened.

Comment: Device ready event should be fired when you open the app and before you start using the plugin code. If you see in the sample link i sent earlier, device ready event is fired on body onload and plugin code is invoked after that. Check this out - https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/cordova/events/events.deviceready.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135016/discussion-between-jc-borlagdan-and-gandhi).